# Product of ideals closed set

Tags: functional-analysis, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a topological ring (in fact $R$ is metrizable) and let $I,J$ denote ideals of $R$. Suppose also that they are closed with respect the topology of $R$. Is it always true that the product ideal $(I \cap J)J$ is closed?

Comment: I guess your definition of topological ring includes something about being Hausdorff? I would be really surprised if I forgot that all rings with appropriately continuous operations were metrizable...

Comment: @rschwieb: yeah its Hausdorff.